# stdout().flush() doesn't render prompt

Tags: rust, io, command-line-interface

I'm trying to build a simple cli discord clone and I've got a user input prompt.

My issue is that the prompt doesn't render until after I've pressed enter on the message that it prompts me to input:

```
pub fn prompt(msg: &str, clear_line: bool) -> String {
    let mut input = String::new();
    print!("{}", msg);
    
    std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

    // if clear_line {
    //     print!("\033[F{}\r", " ".repeat(input.len() + msg.len() + 4));
    //     std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    // };
    input.trim().to_string()
}
```

I know that using `stdout().flush()` after the print macro should flush the buffer to the terminal and render the text but it doesn't seem to do that until after waiting for the user input.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

(I've tried it in the VS Code terminal, alacritty with bash and fish shells so I'm pretty sure it's not my terminal being weird)

Comment: Can't reproduce on macOS, what OS are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce either with Xfce-terminal or Xterm on Linux.

Comment: It's not the problem but, in the `clear_line` part, `\033` should be replaced with `\x1b` (see [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#character-escapes))

Comment: Maybe (pure guess) you use a wrapper which pipes the output of your rust program and repeats it? In this case, even if the source (your rust program) flushes its output, these characters are consumed by the second program. Then, if this second program is line-buffered (very common), the actual output only appears, in the end, when a `\n` is detected.

Comment: Try it with `let _ = write!(std::io::stdout(), "{msg} ");` instead of the `print!(…)`.

Comment: i managed to solve the problem but it was a bit of a headache, pretty much other text was being rendered over the top

the project basically has a system where it sends a message to a server, whenever the table on the server gets updated, it triggers a callback in the client which interrupts the program and prints something to the screen (i'm presuming this runs in a separate thread or something but that's not relevant). every time my function sent the input back to the client and rewrote the prompt, the prompt was overwritten by the response, fix: adding delay before prompt for server res

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve the problem but it was a bit of a headache, pretty much other text was being rendered over the top the project basically has a system where it sends a message to a server, whenever the table on the server gets updated, it triggers a callback in the client which interrupts the program and prints something to the screen (i'm presuming this runs in a separate thread or something but that's not relevant). every time my function sent the input back to the client and rewrote the prompt, the prompt was overwritten by the response,

the solution: adding a small delay before the prompt so that the prompt will most likely not be rendered until the server responds (i've got the delay at 50ms but might increase to 250 or so to account for higher latency users, or maybe make a custom solution, idk)

```rust
pub fn prompt(msg: &str, clear_line: bool) -> String {
    std::thread::sleep(core::time::Duration::from_millis(50));

    let mut input = String::new();
    print!("{}", msg);

    std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();

    if clear_line {
        print!("\x1b[1A\x1b[2K");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
    };
    input.trim().to_string()
}
```

and this was my code being called in a separate thread by the library i'm using:

```rust
pub fn render_message(message: &Event) {
    let username = username_from_identity(&message.sender);
    let timestamp = render_timestamp(message.sent);

    let Some(message) = &message.event else {
        return
    };

    match message {
        EventType::Message(text) => {
            println!("{} {} :: {}", timestamp, username, text);
        },
        EventType::Namechange(change) => {
            println!("{} {} => {} <changed name>", timestamp, change.old_name, change.new_name);
        },
        _ => return, // TODO: implement other event types
    };

    //let channel = render_channel(message.channel_id);
}
```

thanks anyway for the suggestions, i wasn't expecting to make my first post on stack overflow and not get any toxic responses XD